# cannot create weak reference to 'classobj' object

Tags: c#, python-2.7, ironpython

I am trying to run the python Script in a C# program using `Iron Python` I am getting this type of Error:

cannot create weak reference to 'classobj' object

I am using this code for running the python code

```
var ironPythonRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();
try
{
    dynamic loadPython = ironPythonRuntime.UseFile("Program.py");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```